# Ошибка с применением дополнительного класса к блоку на мобильном устройстве

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Ниже вставил пример кода, вся фишка в том что при сужении экрана код меняется, но если я выбираю мобильное устройство, у которого ширина меньше указанной в условии, то ничего не происходит.

```js
function SCREENmove() {
  width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
  height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  if (width > 799) {
    $('.node').addClass("response")
  } else {
    $('.node').removeClass("response")
  }
}
$(window).resize(SCREENmove);
$(document).ready(SCREENmove);
```

```css
.node {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  background: #CDDC39;
}
.node.response {
  background: #FF9800;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="node"></div>
```

работает при сужении:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

мобильная (класс не удалился):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что должно происходить? У вас если ширина меньше то удаляется класс "response" которого изначально нет в верстке. Если ширина на телефоне меньше 799 пикселей то ничего происходить и не будет.

Comment: @DmitriyKondratiuk, для этого и задал разные цвета, если горит оранжевым значит класс есть. Если включить просмотр с мобильного устройства, то горит оранжевым (класс есть) к тому же он есть в коде, класс не удалился. Если же просто сужать экран то класс удаляется

Comment: Ну в вашем примере изначально "response" класса нет `<div class="node"></div>`.

Comment: Оранжевый цвет указан для класса response,смотрите внимательно. На настольной версии (если ширина указана больше 799) появляется response при сужении он пропадает, но на мобильном класс остается хотя ширина меньше 799

Comment: @DmitriyKondratiuk поменял скрины чтобы было понятно

Comment: У вас изначально на странице есть класс `response`, Или он добавляется/удаляется через скрипт?

Comment: @DmitriyKondratiuk не вставлен, исходники выше

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов проверяйте значение width, если класс не удаляется, значит условие не срабатывает)

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов у меня заработало на мобиле, проверял на jsfiddle все в порядке, дело в том что у меня не доходила ширина до подходящей под условие. width на который вы указываете сверху немного отличается, посмотрите в сторону `meta scale` атрибута. Скорее всего из за него проблема

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">` в `<head></head>`
Без него `document.documentElement.clientWidth` не верно возвращает ширину экрана в режиме эмулятора, например, в опере это всегда 980px не зависимо от ширины эмулятора. Поэтому и есть, он не "не удалился", а наоборот добавился, т.к. ширина возвращается больше, чем 799px